# How to include animated png sequence in iMessage Sticker Extension?

Tags: swift, xcode, animation, png, imessage

I am creating a swift custom iMessage Sticker extension to embed within an existing iOS application, I can add single png's as stickers:

i.e.
 createSticker(asset: "myStickerName", localizedDescription: "First Sticker")
...guard let stickerPack = Bundle.main.path(forResource: asset, ofType:"png")

but how would I add a sequence of png images as a single animated Sticker?

Answer (score 0):

Add Sticker Sequence as if you would add a simple sticker.
[image]

Then drag and drop your png images.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response Max, But I am adding my png stickers to my browserViewController programatically, How can I add a png sequence programmatically?

Comment: I thought you were asking about Sticker Pack Application. In iMessage application save your png sequence as APNG (animated PNG) and initialize you MSSticker object with it.

Comment: To quickly create APNGs use a tool like PNG Animator. Want to compress? I've used Pngyu to quickly compress individual frames before combining them to APNG. Keep in mind that sequences can't be bigger than 500kb each.

Comment: Hy @MaxPevsner how can we save my sequence into animated png , i need to get that sequence and add programatically in my mssticker object.

Comment: @ShauketSheikh Did you find a solution? I need to do this too.

Comment: @MaxPevsner i am doing what you showed in your response but everytime I drop the files in the sticker sequence, nothing happens!? I can see the + when i drag over the area and when i let go you would think it would add the images but it does not!?

Comment: Hi @Learn2Code, check if your images are in the correct format.